# User does not persist after begin logged in

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

I am building my first Elixir app using Guardian and I am having an issue where a User can log in and be authenticated, but upon redirect to the next page the `conn` no longer stores the user information and `Guardian.Plug.is_authenticated?` returns false.

`session_controller.ex`

```
  ....
  def create(conn, %{"session" => %{"email" => email, "password" => password}}) do
    case PhoenixApp.Auth.authenticate_user(email, password) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> PhoenixApp.Auth.login(user)
        |> put_flash(:info, "Welcome back!")
        |> redirect(to: "/users")

      {:error, _reason} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:error, "Invalid username or password.")
        |> render("new.html")
    end
  end
  ...
```

`router.ex`

```
  ...
  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  scope "/", PhoenixAppWeb do
    pipe_through [:browser]

    get "/signup", UserController, :new
    get "/login", SessionController, :new
    post "/login", SessionController, :create
    delete "/logout/:id", SessionController, :delete
  end

  scope "/", PhoenixAppWeb do
    # Protected routes
    pipe_through [:browser, :auth]

    resources "/users", UserController, except: [:new]
    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  # Auth pipeline
  pipeline :auth do
    plug(PhoenixApp.Auth.AuthAccessPipeline)
  end
  ...
```

`auth.ex`

```
  ...
  def login(conn, user) do
   conn
    |> Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)
    |> assign(:current_user, user)
    |> IO.inspect
    |> put_user_token(user)
  end
  ...
```

`auth_access_pipeline.ex`

```
defmodule PhoenixApp.Auth.AuthAccessPipeline do
  @moduledoc false

  use Guardian.Plug.Pipeline,
    otp_app: :phoenix_app,
    error_handler: PhoenixApp.Auth.AuthErrorHandler

  plug(Guardian.Plug.Pipeline,
    module: PhoenixApp.Guardian,
    error_handler: PhoenixApp.Auth.AuthErrorHandler
  )

  plug(Guardian.Plug.VerifySession, claims: %{"typ" => "access"})
  # plug(Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated)
  # plug(Guardian.Plug.LoadResource)
end
```

The `IO.inspect(conn)` from my `login` method returns a JSONified User struct for the user that just signed in in the `assigns` key under `current_user`, and also stores a `user_token` with a token. If you inspect the `conn` after redirect to `/users`, the `current_user` in assigns is `nil` and there is no `user_token`.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol is stateless. This means that `redirect_to` returns nothing then **the instruction to the browser how to load another(next) page**.

**conn** in the auth request disappears with all the stored user resources and tokens after the `redirect` is called.

Now browser initiates **new connection** to the server, which creates absolutely new **conn**, which knows nothing about previous (and can be for example handled by another server if one has a cluster).

So, how to "store state" (in our case - user resource) **between** connections?

With **cookies** of course. One should put **user token** inside cookie in one request, and retrieve the token from the cookie in all the next requests.

Fairly saying, **Guardian** has two different ways to store and retrieve token in/from cookie: directly with [remember_me](https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/Guardian.Plug.html#remember_me/5)/[VerifyCookie Plug](https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/Guardian.Plug.VerifyCookie.html) or with sessions: [put_session_token](https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/Guardian.Plug.html#put_session_token/3)/[VerifySession Plug](https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/Guardian.Plug.VerifySession.html)

`put_session_token` is automatically called inside `sign_in`, so you the pipelines should include plugs to work with sessions.

Comment: I edited my original post to show my auth pipeline and updated my `router.ex` to show which routes are now protected and which are not. I have tried including the plug for verifying the session in my pipeline, however if I do so I will get an `invalid token` message immediately after signing in and redirecting to the users index.

Comment: I still don't see the pipelines in your router file. Maybe the problem is because you deleted sessions plug from browser pipeline

Comment: The protected routes are being piped through the authline: `pipe_through [:browser, :auth]`, do you mean something additional is required?

Comment: I misunderstood your comment, I have expanded the code to show the `:browser` pipeline. It is not modified from the default after generating a new phoenix app, and the `:fetch_session` plug was not removed.

Comment: You are using `Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)`. But the documentation tells us use `MyApp.Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)`

Do you have this module in your code?

Comment: I have my `Guardian` module aliased. `Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)` is pointing to the `MyApp.Guardian` module, which in turn is using the Guardian package (`use Guardian, otp_app: :phoenix_app`)

Comment: Can you check, that after your login, conn has the user’s token in season? Via `get_session`? And that the session in the next request is the same on the next request?

Comment: After calling `login` from my `auth.ex`, I don't have a user token in the session. I only have `guardian_default_token` and `_csrf_token`, even though this method invokes the `Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)` which I thought should be creating the user session..

Comment: Yep, here is the problem. You can manually do the same checks that sign_in do, and understand why it’s not writing in the session